# Cocoa OS X NSLevelIndicator type

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nslevelindicator

The default `NSLevelIndicator` styles are shown in the image below:

[image: http://d-bug.chaos-interactive.de/data/cocoaext/li_preview.png]

How can I make the level indicator to look the same as this one in the Sound.prefPane of the System Preferences app (`Input level`)?

[image: http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT2508/en_US/HT2508-Lion-SoundInput-001-en.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own control.

There's no [default control](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TPXREF104) in Cocoa (up to and including OS X 10.9)  - or even a [custom control](http://cocoacontrols.com/controls?page=1&platform_id=mac-os-x) I'm aware of - providing that style out of the box for you.